If you feel tired tomorrow night
I made up this sentence and I think it’s correct but I am not sure.
“If you feel tired tomorrow night, you’ll be able to go to bed.”
I am not sure if using conditional here is correct. Maybe it could cause ambiguity. It sounds like your getting tired makes you have the ability to go to bed, which doesn’t make sense.

What make you confused about the correctness of the sentence? You need to point it out.

I am not sure if using conditional here is correct. Maybe it could cause ambiguity.

You need to point it out - what possible ambiguity are you thinking might exist? That if you don't feel tired tomorrow night, you won't be able to go to bed? That would be a truly bizarre interpretation!

It sounds like your getting tired makes you have the ability to go to bed, which doesn’t make sense.

To remove any ambiguity, maybe you should say " ... you will be able to go to sleep

I don't see any 'ambiguity'. If you feel [some negative thing] tomorrow night, you'll be able to [do something to make it better]. A completely normal sentence. If you feel hungry tomorrow night, you'll be able to have a snack. If you feel lonely tomorrow night, you can call me on your phone. If you feel cold tomorrow night, you'll be able to put on a coat.

I don’t know why but it seems that I am the only one that feels this way. It just feels like the completion of the condition makes the person gain the ability. Like this: “If you feel anxious, you’ll be able to talk to your friends.”

@ChienTeLu - that is not how such an utterance is perceived by a native speaker. It's a common formulation, as my comment was intended to convey. It means 'if you feel some bad thing, you will have a solution.

So I can say “If you feel bored tomorrow night, you’ll be able to play the piano.”?

@ChienTeLu - if conjunction 1. (introducing a conditional clause) on the condition or supposition that; in the event that. (Oxford Languages), so YES. My bold emphasis.

I've added your (erroneous) ideas about possible ambiguity to the question itself. If you'd edited that into the question rather than posted as comments, you might not have got the downvotes (not mine, but I don't see why I should have to do this for you! :)

If you practice making friends, then you'll be able to talk to friends. If  you feel tired tomorrow, you won't be able to go to bed early because we'll be dancing with our friends.

While the sentence isn't incorrect, the awkwardness you're feeling comes from the use of "be able to" which in this context implies that you are granting the person permission to perform the action, or that the action won't be an option until tomorrow night. Here are a few more natural phrasings that keep the same basic meaning:

If you feel tired tomorrow night, you could go to bed.
If you feel anxious tomorrow, talk to your friends.

Here's a more natural use of "be able to" in this context:

If he moves that pawn, you'll be able to take his queen.

Here, someone is advising a chess move such that, upon a given condition, the action can be taken. The action isn't an option now, but once the condition is true, they will be able to take the action. Removing "be able to" from this sentence, unlike the first two examples, changes the meaning, e.g. "If he moves that pawn, take his queen" is clearly a command, rather than a suggestion.
I would only use "be able to" like this when the action isn't a current option but will become an option by that time in the future.
Going back to the original examples, adding some context that turns going to bed/talking to friends into an action that only becomes available in the future removes the awkwardness:

These night shifts are difficult and we've all been working hard. Thankfully, the next few nights are going to be slow. I need you all up tonight, but if you feel tired tomorrow night, you'll be able to go to sleep*.
I know this trip to Antarctica was hard on you, and being cut off from everyone made you anxious. We'll be back soon, though. If you [still] feel anxious tomorrow, you'll be able to talk to your friends.

*Note that I changed 'bed' to 'sleep' here as 'go to bed' implies that you're going home to your own bed, or a more permanent location that you're sleeping in (maybe a hotel or friend's house), whereas "go to sleep" is more general and could happen anywhere.

Exactly! You understand my struggle here. “Will be able to” makes it sound like the person gain the permission or the ability to sleep if he feels tired, which makes no sense at all. What surprises me is that despite my original sentence being obviously awkward, many native speakers insist it’s 100% natural, which surprises me. Maybe it’s a thing about dialects?

Perhaps it's easier for native speakers to place the sentence in scenarios like my last two examples, where it becomes more natural, as opposed to seeing the awkwardness in the isolated phrase? It's weird in most scenarios to grant someone permission to go to bed or to talk to their friends, these are usually things we can do at will. I doubt it's a dialectical thing, however, I am a native speaker of American English (midwestern) in case I am wrong.

Your sentence is unnatural because of the subject (of course someone can go to bed at night when they feel tired!). It would be natural if the suggested activity was something that they can't do yet but will have the opportunity to do in the future.

@ohshitgorillas Surprisingly, your answer got downvoted, which is weird. I've accepted your answered as the correct one though.

@KateBunting Maybe this context will make "will be able to" feel more natural:
"We actually need everyone to stay alert for 72 hours. The enemy might come anytime. However, if you feel really tried tomorrow night, you'll be able to go to sleep for a while."
Here you are not allowed to go to sleep, but on the condition that you are very tired, you will be able to (allowed) to go to sleep for a while.

Yes, it would be acceptable in that context.

This type of sentence is idiomatic in contexts where the speaker is bringing a fact or situation to the attention of the listener in a reassuring manner:

If you don't like the color I chose when the shirt arrives, you'll be able to return it or exchange it with no trouble.

There are any number of contexts where the statement like the one in the OP's question would be fine.  For example, the listener is  driving five hours to visit family tomorrow, and he can't leave until his work day has ended, so he may be quite tired when he reaches the family house, but not to worry, a guest bedroom has been prepared for him and no one is expecting him to stay up late:

If you feel tired tomorrow night, you’ll be able to go right to bed.


Just a gut feel, but I think a lot of people would use "un-tensed" can rather than future tense will be able to in such contexts. And once that's done, it's more idiomatic to include "always", which leads to "If you feel tired tomorrow night, you can always go to bed early". Again, maybe it's just me, but I'm guessing non-native Anglophones would be far less likely to think there might be any ambiguity there (there's no ambiguity for native Anglophones in the first place, obviously).

@FumbleFingers I don't disagree. But you can shades into permission (cf. You can return the shirt if you don't like the color I chose -- it won't hurt my feelings) whereas "you'll be able" can have the nuance of freedom from impediment. There will be no impediment to going to bed if you're tired. The room is ready.

Yes, but to my mind you can always... most strongly carries the implication You [will] have options, and this option is a perfectly acceptable one if for some reason you don't want to or can't spend a lot of time making your choice. And that's probably the most likely "subtext" for any utterance broadly similar to the OP's example.

@FumbleFingers  I agree that "you can always {verb}" means there's nothing to stop you from {verbing} -- it's an option open to you.
